# What is the derivative of $1\over 2 $$\| P^TS-I\|^2_F$?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of ${1}\over{2}$${\| P^TS-I\|^2_F}$? over $P$?

$P$ is a $n$ by $s$ matrix, $S$ is of the same dimension,

thanks

Comment: The title is type, sorry about that

Comment: What's the varaiable? Also explain the notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frobenius norm of a matrix equals the norm of its transpose. And its square is the same as the scalar matrix product, i.e. 
$$\|X^T\|^2_F = \|X\|^2_F = X:X$$

The differential of the scalar product is just $$d(X:X) = 2X:dX$$

In your particular function $X^T = (P^T\cdot{S}-I)$ and there's a scale factor of $({{1}\over{2}})$ so its differential is

$$ \eqalign {
(S^T\cdot{P}-I):S^T\cdot dP \cr
S\cdot(S^T\cdot{P}-I):dP \cr
} $$

The derivative wrt $P$ is 
$$S\cdot(S^T\cdot{P}-I)$$